# android location base notifications

Tags: java, android, service, push-notification

I want to create an android app

that will send the device location after the app's installation

and every 15 minutes

What is the best way to do so?

1) I can create a timer inside the App's main Activity.

but then it will be stopped when the app is on the background. So I understand I have to create a service.

But then, how do I register it to work from device start up (after turning the device on and forever after)?

2) I saw this push notification [tutorial](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/tutorial_push_notifications_in_5_simple_steps), I think it doesn't fit my needs as the server sends the notification in broadcast, no?

I want different notifications to users based on their current location.

I want the user to actively send GPS location and then receive custom push to his location

(GEO based push notification)

Would you use something like the guy answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318755/send-notifications-based-on-the-users-location)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something on a time-based interval, I suggest looking into `AlarmManager`:

`Alarms (based on the AlarmManager class) give you a way to perform time-based operations outside the lifetime of your application.`

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1):

You can start the service by making a **broadcast Receiver** which listens to **boot completed**. Then start service in it. As far as getting location every 15 minutes is concerned you can use following code to get location every 15 minutes :-

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(usedLocationService, updateTime, updateDistance, this);
```

replace `updateTime` with `90000` for 15 minutes. You should implement locationManager in your `service`.

Comment: but then, i push the location and get JSON from the server. How do I present it locally? at the top bar?

Comment: Simply use notification manager. It is very easy and you will find tons of tutorial on the net.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google map android api, then there is a interface calls 
locationOnChange(LatLng points), this will be called every X min or sec ( X is defined by you ), that bascially gets your current location at giving LatLng point. Then if I was you, I would use NotificationManager to push the notification with the updated point to my phone

Here is the code I would do for this.

```
    //At OnCreate


    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this)

//Google Map interface

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)

//inside I would use the notificationManager to push the location
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.btn_star)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification~~~~")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!~~~~")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(s));

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: but then, i push the location and get JSON from the server. How do I present it locally? at the top bar?

Comment: Just updated the answer above, of cause, change the "Hello World~~~" to the text you wish, and also the setContectTitle and BigText